# mount one directory to another while mapping the original directory's UID to another

Tags: linux, mount

I'd like to mount the directory `/var/www/mysite` to the directory `/home/daniel/mysite`, but also have the user of the mounted files mapped from the original user (`www-data`) to my own user (`daniel`).

So that the file `/var/www/mysite/index.php` who's user is `www-data` will appear in the mounted directory as `/home/daniel/mysite/index.php` and be owned by `daniel` - and alternatively, if I create a file `/home/daniel/mysite/test.php` with my own user, it will be created in the original directory under the user `www-data`

Is it possible? If not, what alternatives do I have so I can use an IDE and still make sure all the files belong to the HTTP server's user?

Comment: Why do you need the files to belong to `www-data`?

Comment: I'm using a CMS (who shall remain nameless) that starts crying when files belong to other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using NFS to solve my conundrum. I used [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) as a base and ended up having the following in `/etc/exports`:

> `/var/www/mysite       localhost(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=33,anongid=33)`

(all in a single line; where 33 is `www-data`'s UID and GID)

and the following in `/etc/fstab`:

> `localhost:/var/www/mysite /home/daniel/mysite nfs4 defaults 0 0`

When I browse the directory it says every file belongs to `www-data:www-data`, but I can create and edit files as if they belonged to my own user.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to create a symbolic link using ln -s to the mysite folder under your home drive after granting yourself write access to everything under the mysite folder.